# ROS and Gazebo: Documentation Soon?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-simulator, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that ROS and Gazebo are both under the umbrella of OSRF, when will we be getting updates to the ROS.org documentation of gazebo?

[The Gazebo website](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install) says "Only install Gazebo from here, and only follow tutorials from this website. Documentation on ros.org for Gazebo is old and not actively maintained." but doesn't provide any basic tutorials like how to subscribe to a message Gazebo generates in ROS. (There are Tutorials for making plugins, but not for basic usage)

It doesn't seem like it helps the community at all to have such a fractured approach to documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63089/ros-and-gazebo:-documentation-soon?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-05-20**:
This is something that should really be looked in to.  Its very confusing, a new standard should be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answers cross-posted here:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2881/ros-and-gazebo-documentation-soon/

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2